# multiple actors in one sequence diagram

Tags: oop, uml, use-case, sequence-diagram

I have a usecase diagram with 4 actors and wanna draw a sequence diagram based on my usecase.
but i don't know how can I show 4 actors in the sequence diagram.is it right to do such a thing?

my use case is like this:

[image: use case]

Comment: 4 actors 4 lifelines?

Comment: yes and there are other objects too.

Comment: and you want to draw a sequence diagram representing one of the use cases where all of the 4 actors do something together (interact) at the same time? Or you want to draw 1 sequence diagram representing 1 use case diagram with many use cases and many actors as one picture with different "name" and different style? I'm asking because usually 1 bubble in the use case diagram (1 use case) turns into 1 sequence diagram (or more..)

Comment: I provided a image like my use case in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would turn one [usage scenario](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/usageScenario.htm) into one (or more) sequence diagram(s). There are some tools that can [do it automatically](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/modeling_basics/generated_sequence_diagram.html).

For example in your case the `Order Food` bubble

[image]

might turn into something like this:

[image]

In this particular sequence diagram there are only 3 (out of 4) actors shown. Those that play a role in this [scenario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scenario_(computing)).

In complex cases drawing multiple sequence diagrams without all those alternate or optional [fragments](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) might be easier for readers.